# ¿Como cambiar el texto de h2 cuando presiono un botón?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net

Contexto:

Necesito cambiar el texto de mi h2 cuando presiono un botón y sin salirme de la pagina, mi h2 dice "Consultas" y tengo 3 botones si aprieto el primer quisiera que me dijera ese h2
"Consultas Guías", si presiono el segundo botón que me diga "Consulta Parámetros" y si presiono el tercer botón que mi h2 diga "Consulta Ensambles"

estoy trabajando con asp.net html

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Necesitas hacerlo con C#??? porque si es html esta la respuesta abajo. por favor pon algo de código, estamos tratando de adivinar cual es tu escenario!!!

Comment: Seria bueno completar la pregunta si utilizas ASP.NET Webforms, ASP.NET MVC, ademas tambien que version de .NET Framework utilizas (o incluso si utilizas NET Core o NET5). Para ayudarte mejor. Me sumo tambien a porque necesitas hacer algo en C# en una web (ya que en HTML seria con Javascript, o si utilizas Blazor ya seria otra pregunta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacerlo desde c# podrías agregar un label dentro de tu h2:

Código html:

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h2 id="titulo">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Consultas"></asp:Label>
            </h2>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Consultas Guías" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Consultas Parámetros" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Consultas Ensambles" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
    
        </div>
    </form>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Consultas Guías";
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Consultas Parámetros";
        }

        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Consultas Ensambles";
        }
    }
```